# VideoView triggers OnPreparedListener too early for HLS

Tags: android, http-live-streaming

I want to show user some ProgressDialog while he waits for VideoView to start play HLS. I try to use OnPreparedListener for this, but he triggers to early (after player downloaded m3u8 file, not when video started).

```
VideoView player = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.player);
String httpLiveUrl = "http://example.com/playlist.m3u8";

player.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl));
player.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
player.requestFocus();

player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    progress.dismiss();
}
});

progress.show();
player.start();
```

I didn't find another suitable listner... May be anyone knows sloution?

Comment: Go for Handler.PostDelayed()

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to all. I solved my problem with next hack:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        videoPositionThread = new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                try {
                    int duration = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
                    if (!(videoPosition == duration && videoView.isPlaying())) {
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }
                    videoPosition = duration;
                    handler.postDelayed(videoPositionThread, 1000);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(videoPositionThread, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you help me? what is videoPosition?

Comment: I don't know why my videoview show live video stream after more than 15 or 20 seconds delay.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue, and just found a solution for my needs. Maybe this works for you, too. At least it's tested & works on Android 2.2, 2.3, and 4.2.

The idea is to periodically check if the videoView current position is greater than zero. It's a modification of mikhail's answer. Thanks to mikhail, too :)

```
public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare variables
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    VideoView videoview;
    Runnable videoPositionThread;

    // Insert your Video URL
    String VideoURL = "enter your video rtsp url here";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);
        videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoViewActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Tutorial");
        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

        Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
        videoview.setVideoURI(video);
        videoview.start();

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        videoPositionThread = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int currentPosition = videoview.getCurrentPosition();

                if (currentPosition > 0)
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                else
                    handler.postDelayed(videoPositionThread, 1000);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(videoPositionThread, 0);
    }
}
```