# android onPrepared videoview issue

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

We are developing an android application which shows a rtsp stream in the VideoView control. The following code is used the show the video. Its in a runnable.

```
mProgressDlg.show();
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
mVideoView.startVideo();
```

We have registered the setOnPreparedListener of the VideoView. In the onPrepared method we are dismissing the mProgressDlg.

The code is working fine upto ICS version. But in JB its working fine, but the onPrepared method is firing fastly than other OS. So the progress bar is not showing. It is just appearing and disappearing.

Hope I described the issue correctly. Any solution for this?

Comment: try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831473/)